# Создание защиты для скомпилированного приложения

Tags: c++, delphi, защита

У меня нет исходника приложения (написан на **Delphi** ), но мне нужно сделать, чтобы приложение запускалось только от каких-то условий, заданных мной (к примеру, наличия файла рядом). Целевое приложение я упаковал защитой от взлома.

Вот что мне сразу пришло в голову: сделать приложение, которое проверяет нужные условия и запускает целевое приложение, находящееся в конце файла (примерно как самораспаковывающийся архив). Но в этом сразу минус: в памяти целевое приложение будет "голым", и его можно будет задампить...

В интернете много разных загрузчиков есть, но мне очень не хочется использовать большую библиотеку для такого дела, т.е. если я делаю как сейчас то мой конечный файл весит 800 кб, а так будет 2-5 мб что не то вообще ..

Прошу предложить другой вариант.

**UPD**
попробовал засунуть целевое приложение в ресурсы

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// BIN
//

IDR_SAMPLE_FILE         BIN                     "sample.exe"
```

и потом такая функция:

```
int RunPortableExecutable(HANDLE Image) {
    IMAGE_DOS_HEADER* DOSHeader;
    IMAGE_NT_HEADERS* NtHeader;
    IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER* SectionHeader;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION PI;
    STARTUPINFO SI;
    DWORD* ImageBase;
    CONTEXT* CTX;
    void* pImageBase;
    int count;
    char CurrentFilePath[1024];
    DOSHeader = PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER(Image);
    NtHeader = PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS(DWORD(Image) + DOSHeader->e_lfanew);
    GetModuleFileName(0, CurrentFilePath, 1024);
    if (NtHeader->Signature == IMAGE_NT_SIGNATURE) {
        ZeroMemory(&PI, sizeof(PI));
        ZeroMemory(&SI, sizeof(SI));
        if (CreateProcessA(CurrentFilePath, NULL, NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_SUSPENDED, NULL, NULL, &SI, &PI)) {
            CTX = LPCONTEXT(VirtualAlloc(NULL, sizeof(CTX), MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE));
            CTX->ContextFlags = CONTEXT_FULL;
            if (GetThreadContext(PI.hThread, LPCONTEXT(CTX))) {
                ReadProcessMemory(PI.hProcess, LPCVOID(CTX->Ebx + 8),LPVOID(&ImageBase), 4, 0);
                    pImageBase = VirtualAllocEx(PI.hProcess, LPVOID(NtHeader->OptionalHeader.ImageBase),
                        NtHeader->OptionalHeader.SizeOfImage, 0x3000, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
                
                if (pImageBase == 0) {
                    TerminateProcess(PI.hProcess, 0);
                    CloseHandle(PI.hProcess);
                    CloseHandle(PI.hThread);
                    startup(CurrentFilePath);
                    return 1;
                }
                WriteProcessMemory(PI.hProcess, pImageBase, Image, NtHeader->OptionalHeader.SizeOfHeaders, NULL);
                for (count = 0; count < NtHeader->FileHeader.NumberOfSections; count++) {
                    SectionHeader = PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER(DWORD(Image) + DOSHeader->e_lfanew + 248 + (count * 40));
                    WriteProcessMemory(PI.hProcess, LPVOID(DWORD(pImageBase) + SectionHeader->VirtualAddress),
                        LPVOID(DWORD(Image) + SectionHeader->PointerToRawData), SectionHeader->SizeOfRawData, 0);
                }
                WriteProcessMemory(PI.hProcess, LPVOID(CTX->Ebx + 8), LPVOID(&NtHeader->OptionalHeader.ImageBase), 4, 0);
                CTX->Eax = DWORD(pImageBase) + NtHeader->OptionalHeader.AddressOfEntryPoint;
                SetThreadContext(PI.hThread, LPCONTEXT(CTX));
                ResumeThread(PI.hThread);
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

она работает, вот только не всегда:

```
pImageBase = VirtualAllocEx(PI.hProcess, LPVOID(NtHeader->OptionalHeader.ImageBase),
                            NtHeader->OptionalHeader.SizeOfImage, 0x3000, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
```

в этой части кода - pImageBase иногда получает значение 0, т.е. не удалось занять место в памяти, не понимаю от чего это происходит,  Как при "удачном" так и при "неудачном" срабатывании в переменных значения одни и те же..

```
 if (pImageBase == 0) {
                            TerminateProcess(PI.hProcess, 0);
                            CloseHandle(PI.hProcess);
                            CloseHandle(PI.hThread);
                            startup(CurrentFilePath);
                            return 1;
                        }
```

а тут я проверяю удалось ли сделать операцию и если нет то закрываю приложение и запускаю по новой и это " работает" т.е. иногда 3-4 раза перезапускается .. но понятно что такой вариант плохой, т.е вдруг у кого то будет не запускаться не 3-4 раза а 50... 100...

если кому-то нужно знать, что за функция startup то вот она:

```
VOID startup(LPCTSTR lpApplicationName)
{
    // additional information
    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

    // set the size of the structures
    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));

    // start the program up
    CreateProcess(lpApplicationName,   // the path
        LPSTR(""),        // Command line
        NULL,           // Process handle not inheritable
        NULL,           // Thread handle not inheritable
        FALSE,          // Set handle inheritance to FALSE
        0,              // No creation flags
        NULL,           // Use parent's environment block
        NULL,           // Use parent's starting directory 
        &si,            // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
        &pi             // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure (removed extra parentheses)
    );
    // Close process and thread handles. 
    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
}
```

**UPD**
решил проблему с памятью добавив вот это :

```
NtUnmapViewOfSection(PI.hProcess, LPVOID(NtHeader->OptionalHeader.ImageBase));
```

перед этим

```
pImageBase = VirtualAllocEx(PI.hProcess, LPVOID(NtHeader->OptionalHeader.ImageBase),NtHeader->OptionalHeader.SizeOfImage, MEM_COMMIT | 
MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
```

теперь вопрос, насколько это правильно? или не правильно вовсе?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112646/discussion-on-question-by-getyoufun-----).

Answer (score 3):

*Защищать* скомпилированное и лежащее в бинарнике ПО можно разными способами, но вот *защитить* его так, чтобы точно никто не подкопался, практически невозможно. Посмотрите, например, эту статью: https://habr.com/ru/company/skillbox/blog/440836/ Там написано, что защита без онлайн-проверки очень легко обходится. С онлайн-проверкой сложнее, но тоже обходится. Еще труднее, если у вас хардверный ключ - флешка с цифровой подписью. А в комментариях люди справедливо пишут, что даже от запроса аппаратного ключа можно отбиться. Есть коммерческие предприятия, которые предлагают защиту, например https://www.guardant.ru/ Или еще круче https://www.ilok.com/ Но для этого нужны хорошие деньги.

Так что обычно этим занимаются компании-издатели, а не инди-разработчики.

И еще цитата из статьи на хабре:

> О защите ПО стоит подумать еще на стадии проектирования: после того
> как проект готов частично или полностью, изменить что-то будет
> непросто.

Как вариант кустарной защиты вы можете взять уникальный ID установленной у клиента копии Windows, например, из реестра

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Cryptography\\MachineGuid
```

и при первом запуске на машине приписать хэш от этого значения к одному из своих бинарников. Если такое значение уже есть, второй раз оно уже перезаписываться не должно, а должно сверяться с записью в указанной ветке реестра. Если расходится - программу занесли на другую копию Windows, на другую машину, и она может молча не запускаться, чтобы человек не понял, что срабатывает копи-протекшн.

Fingerprint лучше собрать из нескольких аналогичных веток реестра. Естественно, они не должны меняться от установки, удаления или использования юзером какого-либо софта.

Comment: мне не нужно сделать чтобы вообще никто не мог подкопаться, мне нужно просто разрешить запуск только на компьютерах , которым я дам это разрешение ( без использования серверной стороны, программа должна работать без интернета иначе она бесполезна ). К тому же платные варианты защиты тоже "не интересуют" т.е. я могу сам сделать, только предложите как.

Comment: Посмотрите, я обновил ответ, написал вам одну такую идею.

Comment: ваша идея не совсем идея, т.е. условия запуска я итак вкурсе где взять и какие .. мне надо понять как сделать чтобы запустилось целевое приложение только по моим условиям . Я обновил вопрос, посмотрите может сможете помочь.

Comment: снова обновил вопрос, прошу просмотреть

Answer (score 0):

В итоге вот такой код, у меня вышел, для запуска приложения из ресурсов загружая его в память (теперь работает без сбоев) :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <TlHelp32.h>
#include <winternl.h>
#pragma comment(lib,"ntdll.lib")
EXTERN_C NTSTATUS NTAPI NtUnmapViewOfSection(HANDLE, PVOID);
VOID startup(LPCTSTR lpApplicationName)
{
    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));
    CreateProcess(lpApplicationName, LPSTR(""), NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);
    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
}
int RunPortableExecutable(HANDLE Image) {
    IMAGE_DOS_HEADER* DOSHeader;
    IMAGE_NT_HEADERS* NtHeader;
    IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER* SectionHeader;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION PI;
    STARTUPINFO SI;
    DWORD* ImageBase;
    CONTEXT* CTX;
    void* pImageBase;
    int count;
    char CurrentFilePath[1024];
    DOSHeader = PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER(Image);
    NtHeader = PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS(DWORD(Image) + DOSHeader->e_lfanew);
    GetModuleFileName(0, CurrentFilePath, 1024);
    if (NtHeader->Signature == IMAGE_NT_SIGNATURE) {
        ZeroMemory(&PI, sizeof(PI));
        ZeroMemory(&SI, sizeof(SI));
        if (CreateProcessA(CurrentFilePath, NULL, NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_SUSPENDED, NULL, NULL, &SI, &PI)) {
            CTX = LPCONTEXT(VirtualAlloc(NULL, sizeof(CTX), MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE));
            if (CTX != 0) {
                CTX->ContextFlags = CONTEXT_FULL;
                if (GetThreadContext(PI.hThread, LPCONTEXT(CTX))) {
                    ReadProcessMemory(PI.hProcess, LPCVOID(CTX->Ebx + 8), LPVOID(&ImageBase), 4, 0);
                    NtUnmapViewOfSection(PI.hProcess, LPVOID(NtHeader->OptionalHeader.ImageBase));
                    pImageBase = VirtualAllocEx(PI.hProcess, LPVOID(NtHeader->OptionalHeader.ImageBase),
                        NtHeader->OptionalHeader.SizeOfImage, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);

                    if (pImageBase == 0 ) {
                        TerminateProcess(PI.hProcess, 0);
                        CloseHandle(PI.hProcess);
                        CloseHandle(PI.hThread);
                        startup(CurrentFilePath);
                        return 1;
                    }
                    WriteProcessMemory(PI.hProcess, pImageBase, Image, NtHeader->OptionalHeader.SizeOfHeaders, NULL);
                    for (count = 0; count < NtHeader->FileHeader.NumberOfSections; count++) {
                        SectionHeader = PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER(DWORD(Image) + DOSHeader->e_lfanew + 248 + (count * 40));
                        WriteProcessMemory(PI.hProcess, LPVOID(DWORD(pImageBase) + SectionHeader->VirtualAddress),
                            LPVOID(DWORD(Image) + SectionHeader->PointerToRawData), SectionHeader->SizeOfRawData, 0);
                    }
                    WriteProcessMemory(PI.hProcess, LPVOID(CTX->Ebx + 8), LPVOID(&NtHeader->OptionalHeader.ImageBase), 4, 0);
                    CTX->Eax = DWORD(pImageBase) + NtHeader->OptionalHeader.AddressOfEntryPoint;
                    SetThreadContext(PI.hThread, LPCONTEXT(CTX));
                    ResumeThread(PI.hThread);
                    CloseHandle(PI.hProcess);
                    CloseHandle(PI.hThread);
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// Fork Process From Resource
// Dynamically create a process from a resource file.
bool ForkProcessFromResource(int iResource)
{
    HGLOBAL        hResData;
    HRSRC        hResInfo;
    LPVOID        lpRes;
    LPVOID        lpMemory;
    long int    lSize;
    HMODULE        hModule;
    bool bReturn;
    hModule = GetModuleHandle(0);
    bReturn = false;
    if (!hModule)
        return bReturn;
    hResInfo = FindResource(hModule, MAKEINTRESOURCE(iResource), "BIN");
    if (!hResInfo)
    {
        return bReturn;
    }
    hResData = LoadResource(hModule, hResInfo);
    if (!hResData)
    {
        return bReturn;
    }
    lpRes = LockResource(hResData);
    if (!lpRes)
    {
        FreeResource(hResData);
        return bReturn;
    }
    lSize = SizeofResource(hModule, hResInfo);
    lpMemory = new LPVOID[lSize];
    ZeroMemory(lpMemory, lSize);
    memcpy(lpMemory, lpRes, lSize);
    bReturn = RunPortableExecutable(lpMemory) == 0; 
    FreeResource(hResData);
    delete[] lpMemory;
    return bReturn;
}
```

**UPD**
Всё таки не совсем решило проблему, т.е.  на Windows 10 x64 запускается всегда, а вот на Windows 7 x64 почему-то нет - запустилось с 4го раза, что, теперь, может быть не так?

Comment: Уже обсуждалось, этот способ не надежен: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/921881/240512

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight так я ж размапил память и потом VirtualAllocEx и проверяю результат, и он отрабатывает без ошибки и уже когда запускается процесс то выдаёт ошибку, при чём у меня ошибки нету вообще никогда,а на windows 7 через раз

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight у меня вообще перестало показывать ошибку именно когда добавил  NtUnmapViewOfSection(PI.hProcess, LPVOID(NtHeader->OptionalHeader.ImageBase)); может надо после этого замапить нужный размер образа?

Comment: Все равно это сомнительно. Если размапить участок памяти, но в другой памяти сохранились указатели, ссылающиеся на него, то при попытке работать с этими указателями будет ошибка. Кроме того, работает ли NtUnmapViewOfSection, если участок памяти приходится на загруженный модуль? Странно, если бы можно было размапить такой участок без выгрузки самого модуля.